# How to make a specific matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a square matrix of N length where the number in the last row starts off the next row, and the number repeats after N is reached. I would prefer it to be in a for loop.

EXAMPLE 1:

```
[1 2 3 4;
 4 1 2 3;
 3 4 1 2;
 2 3 4 1]
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
[1 2 3 4 5;
 5 1 2 3 4;
 4 5 1 2 3;
 3 4 5 1 2;
 2 3 4 5 1]
```

Any suggestions?

This is the closest I have got:

```
q =1;
N=4;
for n = 0:N-1
    for m = 0:N-1
        if q < N
           C(n+1,m+1) = q;
           q = q + 1;
        elseif q == N
           C(n+1,m+1) = q;
           q = q + 1;
        elseif q > N
           C(n+1,m+1) = q-1;
           q = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

result:

```
[1 2 3 4
 4 1 2 3
 4 4 1 2
 3 4 4 1]
```

Something messed up from row 2 to row 3, and I not sure where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use for loops, you could do something like this

```
N = 5;
k = 1; % variable to keep track of element value
A = zeros(N, N); % initialize your matrix

for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        A(i, j) = k; % write the value in the element
        k = k + 1; % increase the value by 1
        if (k > N) % exceeded maximum value, loop back to 1
            k = 1;
        end
    end
    k = A(i, j); % for the next row, start with the last value of the column
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually just found another way to do it... but yours is so much more efficient and shorter... My code is embarrassing to show on here after that...

Comment: No problem, but it's surely possible to optimize this solution even more. For example, you can observe that the diagonals of the output matrix always contains the same value: 1 in the main diagonal, 2 in the one above, ...

Answer (score 3):

One solution using a modulo:

```
n = 5;
A = [n:(2*n-1)]-[0:(n-1)].';
R = mod(A,n)+1

% R = 
%   [1 2 3 4
%    4 1 2 3
%    3 4 1 2
%    2 3 4 1]
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw using a modulo someplace else. This way is very useful and it would be awesome if I could use that. However, I need to use a for loop.

Comment: @Bringit665 edit your question, show us what you've already tried and explain us why it does not work.

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have done. Please excuse how messy the code is. I am not the best programmer.

Comment: Haha, don't be ashamed, the goal here is to get an answer and adding your code, even if messy, help us to provide an answer. We are not all-knowing, we all have to start to learn new stuffs at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function [`toeplitz([1 n:-1:2], 1:n)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html).